# wxPython check if object exists

Tags: wxpython, exists, destroy

I want to check if bitmap button exists and if exists, then destroy it and if it don´t exists, then create it. This is code:

```
    try:
        shutdownbtn
    except NameError:
        sbex = False
    else:
        sbex = True

    if sbex:
        self.shutdownbtn.Destroy()
        print "Destroyed"

    if not sbex:
        self.shutdownbtn = wx.Bitmap("bin/Images/wstdwn.png")
        self.wstdwnbtn = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.shutdownbtn)
        self.wstdwnbtn.SetPosition((0, 550))
        self.wstdwnbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.wexit)
        self.wstdwnbtn.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Exit to main menu."))
```

It creates the bitmap button, but doesn't delete it! Why? I really don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using `shutdownbtn` not `self.shutdownbtn`. You will also have to catch an `AttributeError`, not a `NameError`.

Comment: Thank you very much it works. I have it like action of other button, so if i click on it for first time it shows shutdownbtn, but if i click on it for second time,it prints Destroyed, but shutdownbtn isn´t destroyed and if i click for third time it prints Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Comment: Ah, that's because you have removed the button, but the `self.shutdownbtn` still exists. It might be better to keep an attribute like `self.shutdown_showing` to keep track of whether the button is shown or hidden instead of using the existence of the attribute for that.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this:

```
    try:
        self.shutdown_showing
    except AttributeError:
        self.shutdown_showing = False
    else:
        self.shutdown_showing = True

    if self.shutdown_showing:
        self.shutdownbtn.Destroy()
        print "Destroyed"

    if not self.shutdown_showing:
        self.shutdownbtn = wx.Bitmap("bin/Images/wstdwn.png")
        self.wstdwnbtn = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.shutdownbtn)
        self.wstdwnbtn.SetPosition((0, 550))
        self.wstdwnbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.wexit)
        self.wstdwnbtn.SetToolTip(wx.ToolTip("Exit to main menu."))
```

Because it´s still the same...

Comment: No - that has the same problem. In the class's __init__ method you should set shutdown_showing to False, then change the value as you show/hide the button

Comment: To understand why, think through what happens the third time the function is called, when the attribute exists and is set to True, but the shutdown button has been destroyed the second time it was called.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much it´s working! But my destroy code is probably wrong becaouse it prints destroy, but bitmap button is still there. Can you please help me with that?